# Understanding the proof of $\text{Theorem (8.1.7)}$ in Greene's Function Theory of One Complex Varible?

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

In the text "Functions of One Complex Variable" by Steven G. Krantz and Robert E. Greene on (Pg.260) I'm having trouble understanding the proof to $\text{Theorem (8.1.7)}$ specifically how the author constructed the bounds in $(2)$ and $(3)$ utilizing $\text{Lemma (8.1.6)}$ ?

$\text{Theorem (8.1.7)}$

If the infinite product $$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(1+|a_{j}|)$$

converges so then

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(1+a_{j})$$

$\text{Lemma (8.1.6)}$

Let $a_{j} \in \mathbb{C}$ Set

$$P_{N}=\prod_{j=1}^{N}(1+a_{j}), \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \overline P_{N}=\prod_{j=1}^{N}(1+|a_{j}|)$$

Then $|P_{N}-1| \leq \overline P_{N}-1$

$\text{Proof of Theorem (8.1.7)}$

For some $N_{0}$ it holds that $a_{j} \neq 1$ if $j > N_{0}$. One can write for $J > N_{0}$, in $(1)$

$(1)$
$$Q_{j}=\prod_{j=N_{0}+1}^{J}(1+a_{j}) \, \, \text{and} \, \, \overline Q_{j}=\prod_{j=N_{0}+1}^{J}(1+|a_{j}|).$$

If $M > N > N_{0}$, then in $(2)$

$(2)$

$$|Q_{M}-Q_{N}| = |Q_{N}| \cdot \bigg | \prod_{j=N+1}^{M}(1 + |a_{j}|)) \leq |Q_{N}| \bigg | \prod_{j = N+1}^{M}(1+|a_{j}| - 1 \bigg |.$$

Utilizing $\text{Lemma (8.1.6)}$, I made the conclusion in $(3)$

$(3)$

$$|\overline Q_{M}- \overline Q_{N}| = |\overline Q_{N}| \cdot \bigg | \prod_{j=N+1}^{M}(1 + |a_{j}|) \leq |\overline Q_{N}| \bigg | \prod_{j = N+1}^{M}(1+a_{j}) - 1 )\bigg |.$$

Comment: Hmm at first it seems to me only the absolute value is considered. Why does 8.7.1 Apply to arg ?

Comment: They consider both $|a_{j}|$ and $a_{j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have
\begin{align*}
|Q_{M}-Q_{N}|& =   \bigg | Q_{N}\Big(\prod_{j=N+1}^{M}(1 + a_{j})-1\Big)  \bigg | \\
& = |Q_{N}| \bigg |  \prod_{j=N+1}^{M}(1 + a_{j})-1  \bigg |\\
&\leq |Q_{N}| \bigg | \prod_{j = N+1}^{M}(1+|a_{j}|) - 1 \bigg |\tag{using the lemma}
\end{align*}

Comment: What the author did looks very similar to applying the Triangle Inequality but for products is my intuition correct ?

Comment: Between what quantities?

Comment: @Zophikel: are you sure that (3) is without typos?

Comment: Yes @Netchaiev they used a tilde while I used a $\overline$ to denote the partial products an absolute value